# Pin notifications to toppanel in GNOME shell?

Tags: gnome, notification

I just installed and enabled the GNOME shell for ubuntu 11.10. its really nice except that i cannot pin the notifications i want to the top panel. instead theyre on the bottom panel, normally hidden unless i mouseover.

how can i pin these items to the top notification area?

and possibly remove the "ease of access" madness up there

Answer (score 3):

[This extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/192/status-icon-fixer/) may help you.
It moves the bottom panel icons to the top panel.
[image]

PS: [This other extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/) should remove the Accesibility icon.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/ might also work

Answer (score 1):

WebUpd8 posted [an article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/move-icons-from-message-tray-to-top.html) about moving the notifications to the top bar.
And you can use [the noa11y extension](https://github.com/ecoleman/noa11y-colemando.com) to hide the "ease of access" icon, if that's what you mean.